# Jquery / Javascript countdown with mysql & php datetime Y-m-d H:s:m

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime, countdown

Hi i need to make a countdown script using dates in this format (Y-m-d H:m:s), so i retrieve current_datetime and expire_datetime in that format and i need to use them inside some js or js plugin to show up the countdown between these dates.

Does someone knows lightweight js or jquery plugins that accepts the date format showed above?

This is pretty what i need http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html, but it doesn't allows Y-m-d H:m:s format

NB: i need to bind the countdown event to multiple elements on page.

Thanks!.

Comment: using human readable timestamps for production is stupid. you should switch to unix timestamps.

Comment: i asked not to which date format to use for prod

Comment: Why not just convert the dates from one format to the other? Where does the data come from?

Comment: sure but i can't understand how to do that too :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the one you posted a link to, just convert your date string into a date object. This can easily be done by breaking the string down into components using JavasScript's `split` method:

```
var date_split = date_string.split(" ");
var date = date_split[0];
date = date.split("-");
var time = date_split[1];
time = time.split(":");
var date_object = new Date(date[0],date[1],date[2],time[0],time[1],time[2]);
```

Comment: why does this http://pastebin.com/ssGkyXQk returns error in console , date.split() is not definied it says

Comment: was an error on line 5: should be `time.split` - corrected this in my answer.